# How to determine whether a codec has a const ratio 'byte number per character'?

Tags: unicode, converters, icu, iconv

Given an IANA codec name (or, one of those used in iconv/ICU), what is the easiest way to determine whether the codec has a fixed width representation for characters or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ucnv_isFixedWidth()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#a7dde59e660b06fe6a47cc55b38e0a68e):

```c
UErrorCode status;
UConverter* converter = ucnv_open("koi8-r", &status);
if (U_SUCCESS(status)) {
  UBool is_fixed = ucnv_isFixedWidth(converter, &status);
}
```

Comment: And how could I do this with 'iconv'?